# Does FinalBuilder support building a Web Deployment Project?

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project, finalbuilder

I just sent out an internal company mail glorifying Web Deployment Projects. However, some of my colleagues are using FinalBuilder and they asked me if it supports building wdproj files?

My guess is, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did ask the FinalBuilder guys but they haven't answered yet. So I just downloaded the trial and tested it myself. The answer is (at least in version 6.3) it does support web deployment projects. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

I would also say YES - since the wdproj is really just another MSBuild project. But why don't you just ask the guys at FinalBuilder? They're usually very quick and responsive and can give you a definitive, final answer on this :-)